# Xcode 4 not recognizing iPhone as provisioned device

Tags: iphone, xcode

My iPhone has a green dot in the organizer, runs 4.2.1, and I just updated Xcode to 4.0.

When I try to build and run my project on the iPhone, it says that no provisioned devices are connected. It worked in the previous version of Xcode.

I have ensured that the provisioning is up-to-date, and that the project settings have the correct provisioning file selected. I also deleted the `Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1` to be sure that's not it.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar issue. If I set the target to "iOS Device" it says no provisioned device is available. If I explicitly set it to my specific phone in the scheme selector, it works. But it's annoying to have to manually set it to my phone each time after plugging it in.

Comment: Karl, how do you set it to your specific phone? I can't find that anywhere.

Comment: It only shows up after you plug in your phone and it gets recognized by XCode. You may need to set up your device for development from the Organizer window.

Comment: This is a duh moment for me, but I just realized that to run anything on an iOS 6 device you have to use xcode 4.5

Comment: i have this problem on Xcode 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the phone to iOS 4.3, and now it works fine in Xcode.

Answer (score 24):

Go to Build Settings of project, and select All in upper right corner, then make sure that the iOS Deployment Target is 4.2(or what ever your device has on it). Then build, it should work.

Comment: I had a very similar problem, my two devices were both provisioned, but one running 4.2.1 wouldnt be recognized, but the one running 4.3.1 would.  I went and set the deployment target to 3.0 and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you have set the device to "Use in Development" in Organiser.

Comment: That was my problem thanks, i just updated from a beta to the release and it was not set to be used for development :)

Answer (score 1):

Is your iPhone showing up in iTunes?  I had a similar problem a few weeks ago, spent some time trying to figure out what was wrong with XCode, and then realized that my iPhone wasn't showing up in iTunes either.  Turns out that an iTunes update had somehow lost the AppleMobileDevices.kext file.

I followed the instructions here to completely remove and reinstall iTunes and it fixed my problem: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1224

Comment: Hi Kris, it does show up in iTunes. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

This has occurred for me. It was confusing the project settings of deployment version with the target setting.

So take note that you are changing the deployment version of the specific target you are building (under TARGETS->TargetName) and not just the for the project (PROJECT->ProjectName). The target setting may override the project setting.

Set Build Settings with the options "Basic/Levels" to see what the Resolved (actual) setting for the deployment target will be.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for a moment, on a device that was previously fine, but I just closed and reopened both iTunes and Xcode and it was fine when I re-opened XCode.  Not sure whether closing iTunes fixed it or closing XCode did, but either way it worked for me.  Definitely a first step to try if your phone previously worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. Apparently, all I had to do was restart Xcode